# How do I configure a Trigger action on entity duplication

Tags: content-hub, content-hub-scripting

A *duplicate* operation for entities exists within Content Hub. How can I configure a **trigger** to fire an action when an entity is *duplicated*`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can create a trigger which will fire an action whenever a duplicate entity will be created.
Lets take an example of an asset, create a new trigger and select objective `"entity creation"`, you can select execution type `"In background"` which is recommended.

[image]

On the condition tab select `add definition` and choose Asset and start adding conditions. See the example screenshot: I have added 2 conditions

[image]

In the action tab you can select any action of your choice which will be fired when the condition will match.